# Track the email delivery status with GMAIL API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-api, gmail-api

We are using Gmail API for the mail sending functionality. Would like to get when the mail is delivered or bounced.

Nuget package which we are using: `Google.Apis.Gmail.v1`

```
Message outmsg  = service.Users.Messages.Send(msg, "me").Execute();
```

after calling this method, we are getting `message id`, `labelsid`,`Threadid`

What would be the best way to achieve this using .Net C#.?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Read Receipt](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9413651?hl=en) is not available in the Gmail api. So when you send an email there is no way for you to request that you be notified when the mail has been sent.  You could add a [feature request.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191602%2B)

you might be able to detect bounce if you sent up [push](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) notifications on the inbox.

Comment: DalmoTo Is there a way to get notified in my app when I got a new email in my gmail inbox using gmail api?

Comment: Depends upon what you mean by notified.  Push notifications would notifiy your application.